# sql- Inner join to update multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I need to update division column from table B to table A using user_id column.I need to run a sql query for a laravel project to update table A.
The scenario is like below -
Table A:

```
user_id  division_id assessment_id posting_id
   2                  2             2
   3          6       55            3
   5          7       6             67
```

Table B:

```
user_id  division_id  remarks
   2        8          a
   3        4          b
   3        7          c
   3        8          d
   5        9          f
```

desired output after joining-
Table A:

```
 user_id  division_id assessment_id posting_id
   2        8          2             2 
   3        6          55            3
   3        4
   3        7
   3        8
   5        7          6             67
   5        9
```

I tried to run the below query:

```
   $result = DB::statement("UPDATE A t1
                        INNER JOIN B t2
                            ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
                     SET t1.division_id = t2.division_id;");
```

But this query is not inserting multiple rows into table A for same user_id.
I just need to copy division_id column from table B into table A.
What should be the query for getting desired output?

Comment: UPDATE does not INSERT.. You appear to be looking for UNION but why as 2/null in tableA disappeared in your result?

Comment: would you please help to make the INSERT query to change table A.
is it better to use any loop? @P.Salmon

Comment: why has 2/null in tableA disappeared in your result?

Comment: if there is a null value in Table A, and there is data in Table B; then null value should be updated by data of table B. @P.Salmon

Comment: Any indexes on table a?

Comment: yes there is id column in table A.@P.Salmon

Comment: What should be in case when Table A have one record for user without division_id and Table B have more then one record for same user with different division_id's ?

Comment: Does combination user_id+division_id unique in table A?

Comment: multiple records from table B with same user_id needs to be inserted in table A. in that case,  table A will have some rows with some columns of null value. @SlavaRozhnev

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(TableB::all('user_id'  ,'division_id') as $data)
    TableA::create($data);

TableA::where('division_id',null)->delete();
```